# Statistics based marketing campaign measurement tools

Tags: sas, business-objects, cognos

Currently using SAS as measurement engine and Business Objects as display layer. Looking to develop a new, faster, slicker solution. Has anyone developed or purchased a campaign measurement reporting system? This solution should measure everything from email stats, web stats, customer activity, lift, ROI, etc.

Ok.. I'm researching and finding nada... We are working with a team from India and they want to re-write everything from scratch.. Any solutions out there at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was a consultant, we either rolled our own or used SAS (or a combination of the two).

Answer (score 3):

If you are already using SAS, have you looked at their [Marketing Automation software](http://www.sas.com/solutions/crm/mktauto/index.html#section=1)?

---

**Update:**
Just saw a [press release](http://www.sas.com/news/preleases/campaignmanagementSGF09.html) from SAS about a new "Software as a Service" Campaign Management solution.  Might be worth checking out for this.

Comment: Yes.. It is not their best product. The Marketing Automation is not the problem. It is the measurement. Even though they state that the tool encompasses measurement and analysis, it's very manual and adhoc. The marketing management side of the tool is weak as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another vote for roll your own, it's mad that this area is so under served. The expense of building your own solution from the ground up, and the hassle of managing a remote team makes me think you may get further by integrating some existing tools.

Google Analytics for web usage has an API, there are many web log tools, you then need to bolt in the customer figures from your end of things.

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt you could do much better than SAS in this area. Especially if you pick up some of thier specialist packages.

You could have a look at R which is a pretty slick open source statistics package. Unfortunately its not used very much for marketing; most of the examples and freely available code is geared towards biochemistry, genetics etc.